# imread() of opencv in python is not working for any image

Tags: python, opencv, imread

I am trying to read images using imread() function of opencv, and thereby trying to show what I read. But its unable to read anything.

```
import cv
import sys

# Get user supplied values
imagePath = sys.argv[1]
cascPath = sys.argv[2]

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

# Read the image
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
cv2.imshow("Image read", image)
```

Thats my code in python, I am using command prompt for execution and thereby:

```
C:\> C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Divy\Desktop\FaceDetectmaster\face_detect.py C:\\Users\\Divy\\Deskop\\FaceDetect-master\\abba.png C:\\Users\\Divy\\Desktop\
\FaceDetect-master\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 271
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Divy\Desktop\FaceDetect-master\face_detect.py", line 13, in <mo
dule>
    cv2.imshow("Images read", image)
cv2.error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\high
gui\src\window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function
cv::imshow
```

Comment: Did you make sure that imagePath points to an existing image?
Try to `print imagePath` and check if folder and file exist.

Comment: try `print(image)` to check that the image is not `None`

Comment: You don't need the double "\\" in your command line arguments for the .png or the .xml files.